# Methods for real time object detection and tracking without neural network

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, object-detection

For a bachelors thesis, I need to count people using a video camera, and this as correct as possible. For this problem I make use of Python together with OpenCV. I know the neural networks like a CNN is the best solution to try and do this. Now the problem here is that for my thesis, I should not use Neural Networks.

I have been researching this topic quite often, but I keep finding object detection and tracking with Neural Network models on Tensorflow and Keras (Yolo, Mobilenet).
The only 'old school' methods that I have found is: background subtraction with mean width and height of a person and a method using HOG with SVM.
Are there any other algorithms I can use? (like knn or random forest instead of SVM)

Another question I still have and can't find a real answer too is how to use this in a video instead of an image. Do you split up the video frame by frame and then detect the person? Or is there another approach for this that I haven't found yet? I feel like doing the object recognition and detection for each frame will be pretty intensive for the machine it's running on.

Will it also be possible to detect multiple people in one frame?

I really hope somebody can help me with this matter, as I have been stuck on this part of my thesis for quite some time now. I want to make some progress again! Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a lot of literature on crowd density estimation from pre-CNN times - try to search for "crowd density estimation survey" on Google Scholar for a starting point. Articles earlier than 2010 are probably not using neural networks. I've skimmed over a few surveys, and it looks as if there were a lot of different approaches, e.g. using texture analysis, but I would guess that none of them can outperform a state of the art net like Faster-RCNN or Yolo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first method - HAAR cascades as features + AdaBoost as classifier. Faster but worst - LBP instead HAAR.
2. HOG + linear SVM. And more: CoHOG, DPM,...
3. ICF (integral channel features) + forest.

This is all the most important.

**Edit 1**: 
And you can use more features (colors, symmetry features) and reduction technique: PCA, PLS etc. For example linear SVM is very fast but not robust for noise. Some researchers used reduction for feature vector size and gave the better results. A good paper "Vehicle Detection using Partial Least Squares": https://anikem.github.io/papers/Kembhavi_VehicleDetection_PAMI2011.pdf
But DNNs showed much better results.

Comment: I will look at them! Thanks a lot

Comment: I am so sorry to bother you again, but I have found out about these algorithms. The only thing I can't find is why to use these 'combos'. Why not use HOG as feature extraction with forest as classifier? Why is it always HOG with a support vector classifier? why not HAAR + SVM. What am I not seeing?

Comment: It's evolution. Only the most stable combinations remain.
HAAR with integral image or LBP + AdaBoost is very fast,  it was a revolution in computer vision: smiles, faces, eyes detection in photo cameras.
HOG + linear SVM was very robust for objects with structure: faces (in dlib library), pedestrians, license plates etc. CoHOG was used in Toshiba for automotive vision.
ICF was very good for GPU before  DNN expansion.